# Redux: Can we use the Redux state object as the form model object?

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux

I am a bit new to redux and I need a bit of guidance from an expert. I do have a packageReducer (packageState) which looks like below,

```
const initialState = {
    packageList: packageListInitialState,
    package: {id:'', name: '', action: '', isReusable: false},
};

export default function packageState( state = initialState, action ) {
    switch ( action.type ) {
        case FETCH_PACKAGE_LIST_SUCCESS:{
            return Object.assign( {}, state,  action.payload );
        }

        case FETCH_PACKAGE_SUCCESS:{
           return Object.assign( {}, state,  action.payload );
        }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

In my create/edit package form, can i use the packageState.package as a model object for the form. Or should I take a copy of the state and use that as a model object? 
Below is the input feild that I have used in the render

```
<input id="packageName"
     name="name"
     required
     requiredMessage='please enter the name.'
     value={ packageState.package.name }
/>
```

Can anyone tell me whats right?

Comment: What is `packageState`? Given code you have posted it is a function. Why do you expect it to have `package` property?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, I think the OP is using mapStateToProps function and getting the state returned by the reducer, so that should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely make use of direct state property returned from the Reducer, however any change in the value should trigger an action that updates the state,

Also Package is an array in the reducer and you are treating it as an object in the container, which will lead to errors.

And the way you are setting state in the reducer is wrong since it will replace the entire state and not a single key in the state.

Modify you code to something like

```
const initialState = {
    packageList: packageListInitialState,
    package: {id:'', name: '', action: '', isReusable: false},
};

export default function packageState( state = initialState, action ) {
    switch ( action.type ) {
        case FETCH_PACKAGE_LIST_SUCCESS:{
            return Object.assign( {}, state,  : {packageList: action.payload} );
        }

        case FETCH_PACKAGE_SUCCESS:{
           return Object.assign( {}, state, {package: action.payload 
              });
        }

        case UPDATE_PACKAGE_NAME: {
             return Object.assign( {}, state,  {package: 
                    Object.assign({}, state.package, {name: action.newName}) 
                    });
         }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But im not triggering an action in everyday data change. My assumption was once the data is been changed the value will get reflected in the packageState.package.name. and once the user clicks the save button im passing the state object (which is the form model ) again so that it will be passed to the server. Is that wrong ?

Comment: In that case you need to maintain a local state that is initialized based on the redux store value and then change in input is reflected in change in localState, when you click save, you should update the store and pass the data to server

Comment: you mean to do something like this in render method and then access through the local state package? 
`self.setState({
 package : packageState.package,
});`

Comment: yes, set a local state in componentWillMount and then set value based on local state.